# Adding a RLMObject to another objects RLMArray only works first time

Tags: objective-c, realm

For the chat part of my application im trying to persist the conversation data into the device so the user does not need to refresh every time he/she opens the app.

After fetching all the messages from the database I loop through the array and store them in the conversation models messages property (RLMArray).

Since each message has a primary key, I also check the realm to see if that message already exists before adding it to the conversation messages. This works fine the first time I use the app, but if I run it again I get this error:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Can't set primary key property 'serverID' to existing value '1355'.'
```

Here is my code to add the messages to the realm

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        for (Message *model in messageArray) {
            NSLog(@"message model: %@", model);
            TERMessage *message = [[TERMessage alloc] initWithMessage:model];
            TERMessage *existingObject = [self.model.messages objectsWhere:@"serverID == %@",message.serverID].firstObject;
            NSLog(@"existing object: %@", existingObject);
            if (existingObject == nil) {
                [self.model.messages addObject:message];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"not being aded");
            }
        }
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, you're querying to see if a `TERMessage` object with the same `serverID` already belongs to `self.model`. That being said, while it's possible that another `TERMessage` object isn't already being linked to `self.model`, it's easily possible that the object still exists in the Realm (i.e. so it's in the `TERMessage` table in the Realm file).

If that's the case, then when you're creating this second `TERMessage` object and trying to add it to `self.model`, Realm is trying to add it to the `TERMessage` table and discovering another object with the same primary key already exists.

To fix this, you'll need to make your query logic a little more thorough to make sure it properly catches the original object when this happens.

Firstly, you can use `[RLMObject objectForPrimaryKey:]` to see if an object with the primary key already exists. If it does, you can then use the inverse relationship feature of Realm to see if it already belongs to `self.model`:

```
@interface TERMessage : RLMObject
//... other properties
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *models;
@end

// --

@implementation TERMessage
+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
        @"models": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:Message.class propertyName:@"model"],
    };
}
@end

// --

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for (Message *model in messageArray) {
    NSLog(@"message model: %@", model);

    // Check to see if an entry exists and it is a linked object of our model object
    TERMEssage *previousMessage = [TERMessage objectForPrimaryKey:message.serverID];
    if (previousMessage != nil && [previousMessage.models indexOfObject:self.model] != NSNotFound) {
        continue;
    }

    // If the object exists, but it's not assigned to the model, assign it
    if ([previousMessage.models indexOfObject:self.model] == NSNotFound) {
        [self.model.messages addObject:previousMessage];
        continue;
    }

    //Create and add a new message object
    TERMessage *message = [[TERMessage alloc] initWithMessage:model];
    [self.model.messages addObject:message];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: This works! the properties have different names in my project but the process works! thanks!